# Swift: How to return to the same instance of my UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, instance

I have a button in my `SettingsViewController` that when pressed, I want to present the same instance of my `TimerViewController` each time the button is pressed.

[image: [This is what it looks like]]

I think I have gotten fairly close with this post here, [iOS Swift, returning to the same instance of a view controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29993085/ios-swift-returning-to-the-same-instance-of-a-view-controller?answertab=active#tab-top). So if you could point me to saving the instance of `TimerViewController`, that would work the best.

This is the code I have right now -

```
var yourVariable : UIViewController!

if yourVariable == nil {
   let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
   yourVariable = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("timer") as! TimerInterface
        }
presentViewController(yourVariable, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: what is the problem with the code?

Comment: I need a way to go back to the same instance of `TimerViewController`. I have a good way of instantiating first, but I don't know how to return back to the same instance.

Comment: Your code should work.

Comment: but this is exactly what the code you posted does! the problem is that if your `SettingsViewController` itself gets dismissed the saved instance of the `TimerViewController` also gets deallocated and recreated the next time...

Comment: @AndréSlotta I think you're right. How do I make sure that `SettingsViewController` doesn't get dismissed? And I was in the understanding that `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("timer")` creates a new instance each time.

Comment: i think the way to go is something else... what exactly happens in your `TimerViewController`?

Comment: add a `print` line with the `instantiate` line. I think you'll see it's not being called again.

Comment: @Tim @AndréSlotta Yes, I did manage to get it working. The `instantiate` was working, but it was being run again due to the new `SettingsViewController` being created. Thanks again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the code you provided should work. if your `SettingsViewController` gets deallocated though the `timerViewController` also gets deallocated and recreated the next time you present it. so you have to make sure to save its instance at an appropriate location.

```
var timerViewController: TimerViewController!

if timerViewController == nil {
   let timerViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
   yourVariable = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("timer") as! TimerInterface
}

presentViewController(timerViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I dismissed the TimerViewController, which fixed a problem where I was creating a new instance of SettingsViewController. The instantiate was working, but it was being run again due to the new SettingsViewController being created.

Answer (score 0):

The best would be to save the ViewController somewhere , and get back to it .
A way to "get back to it" : 
add

```
var tvc: TimerViewController? = nil
```

inside AppDelegate 
when you get to your Timer (the best would be when you left it , in viewDidDisappear)

you add :

```
(UIApplication.sharedAplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).tvc = self
```

then when you get to the setting , if you want to segue back to the timer

```
let tvc = (UIApplication.sharedAplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).tvc
(UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate? as! AppDelegate).window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(tvc, animated: true , completion: nil)
```

if you ask yourself why should you present it with the rootViewController (last line ) it is because you can present an already active viewController , this will not present an already active vc .

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I did manage to get it working with the accepted response. I hope this can help others if they run into this problem!